# Get previous value with React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a dropdown that controls the text input of the value below. If the user select option `a`, nothing happens. If the user select option `b` it will pre-fill in a default value.

But what if I select option 'a' again, instead of clearing the input, set it to the previous value that the user entered. How can this be done with [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com) so that if a user fills in the input, changes to option b, changes back to option a, still sees his first input?

```
const salutationChanged = (option: string) => {
   if (option === 'b') {
      setValue('firstName', 'Family'));
   } else {
      // reset value to user input (previous state?)
   }
}
```

```
<Select
   {...register('salutation')}
   onChange={(e) => salutationChanged(e.detail.value)}
>
    {salutations.map((salutation) => (
       <SelectOption value={salutation.option}>
          {t(salutation.name)}
       </SelectOption>
    ))}
</Select>
<Input
   {...register('firstName')}
   type="text"
/>
```

In this example, the value will remain 'Family' after changing to b. How do I get the previous state from right before the onChange?

I tried adding `getValue()` but it appears to be async because it will give me the updated values from after if else statements.

Comment: Check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119868/how-to-get-previous-state-value-in-reactjs

Answer (score 1):

React Hook Form doesn't seem to have a built in history or a way to override a value temporarily.

So, you probably have to store the value before the change by yourself.
Take this example, in which I introduce a new state variable `firstNameForRestoration`. It is filled with the `firstName`, using React Hook Form's `getValues` **before** using `setValue`. Then, when the salutation changes again, it is used for restoration.

```
const [firstNameForRestoration, setFirstNameForRestoration] = useState("");

const salutationChanged = (option: string) => {
  if (option === "b") {
    setFirstNameForRestoration(getValues("firstName"));
    setValue("firstName", "Family");
  } else {
    setValue("firstName", firstNameForRestoration);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that is the solution. I tried this but I was thinking about it wrong and tried something like `setFirstName((prev) => setValue('firstname', prev))` which didn't work.

Comment: Actually, on retrospect, this will not work 100%. When you edit the form as it was saved to option b, it will set the value to 'Family' when you switch to option 'a'

Comment: Well, without knowing exactly what you want to achieve and also without the full source code, it is hard to help you out in more detail 